# Reading numbers in scientific notation using bash

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, scientific-notation, blast

As part of an annotation pipeline for *De Novo* fish genomes I need to compare e-values from BLAST to see whether they are lower than a certain threshold.

To get the semantics right I first evaluated one of the othet columns in the blast-output, and it works fine like this:

```
for f in FOLDER/*; do 
myVar=$(head -1 $f | awk '{print $4}') ;
if [[ $myVar -gt 50 ]]; then echo ..... ;done
```

$4 is then a column in the BLAST output with whole numerical values (hit length or something)

However, when I try to change the script to working with the e-values, there is some problems with interpretation of the scientific notation etc...

What I WOULD like is this:

```
for f in FOLDER/*; do 
myVar=$(head -1 $f | awk '{print $11}') ;
if [[ $myVar -gt 1.0e-10 ]]; then echo ..... ;done
```

where $11 points to the e-value for each hit.

Could this be done in a not to cumbersome manner in bash?

Comment: Bash can only handle integers. Switch to a more powerful language like Perl.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Might have to Perl it up then... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`, it is possible:

```
for f in FOLDER/*; do awk '$11 < 1e-10 {print $11}' "$f"; done
```

This doesn't need the variable to be defined first.

Comment: I'm a big fan of awk too. Just in case, I'll mention that awk (and other languages), through the math libraries it is built with, has limitations on precision of really large integer values. Sounds like it doesn't apply to what you're doing, but in never hurts to do some defensive testing. Also, it is perfectly legitimate to accept your own answer after x? hours, there by increasing your rep-points.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Will do some testing, but don't think minor details will cause any problems.

Comment: You might want to add `;exit` to the Awk script after the `print $11` to make it only look at the first line.

Comment: You don't really need the `for` loop either, though. `awk 'FNR == 1 && $1 < 1e-10 { print FILENAME ":" $11 }' FOLDER/*`